# Tweepy odd streaming error - python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am attempting to make a script that searches in the user timeline, then favorites tweets.  For some reason, it isnt working.
I wrote this code:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import *
import tweepy, json

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        data = json.loads(data)
        try:
            api.create_favorite(data[id])
        except:
             pass
        print 'Favoriting tweet id ' + data[id] + ' in twitter timeline...'
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
         print status

l = StdOutListener()
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('x', 'x')
auth.set_access_token('x-x', 'x')
api = tweepy.API(auth)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
userz = api.followers_ids(screen_name='smileytechguy')
keywords = ['ebook', 'bot']
stream.filter(track=keywords, follow=userz)
```

But I am getting this **Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FavTL.py", line 27, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=keywords, follow=userz)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 310, in filter
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

any idea on how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. Don't forget to enable writing through your API-keys

```
consumer_key = '..'
consumer_secret = '..'
access_token = '..'
access_secret = '..'


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        # Twitter returns data in JSON format - we need to decode it first
        decoded = json.loads(data)
        tweet_id = decoded['id']
        api.create_favorite(tweet_id)
        print 'Favoriting tweet id ' + str(tweet_id) + ' in twitter timeline...'
        time.sleep(65)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        if(status == 420):
            print "Twitter is limiting this account."
        else:
            print "Error Status "+ str(status)



l = StdOutListener()
api = tweepy.API(auth)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
userz = api.followers_ids('smileytechguy')
keywords = ['ebook', 'bot']
stream.filter(track=keywords, follow=str(userz))
```

Comment: A few questions:
why is there a time.sleep(65) in there?  Also, if there is a more streamlined way to make it search for the track in user's timeline?  Also, I didn't include it in this question, but when I am running a stream of just track=keywords, I recieve 406 errors sometimes, other times it works.
Also, thanks for properly formatting my question.